# How to improve simple = condition on a large table?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index

Check out the following simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM "teammgr_team" WHERE ("teammgr_team"."real" = true AND "teammgr_team"."name" = 'abc');
```

But it takes too long:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on teammgr_team  (cost=0.00..114772.49 rows=118 width=121) (actual time=24.544..618.185 rows=12 loops=1)
   Filter: ("real" AND ((name)::text = 'abc'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 4752431
 Planning time: 0.066 ms
 Execution time: 618.217 ms
(5 rows)
```

I assume because the table is very large:

```
  count
---------
 4752443
(1 row)
```

This is the table and relevant column:

```
                                       Table "public.teammgr_team"
        Column        |         Type          |                         Modifiers
----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer               | not null default nextval('teammgr_team_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                 | character varying(40) | not null

Indexes:
    "teammgr_team_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "teammgr_team_club_id" btree (club_id)
```

I am not sure if adding an index to a character column is advisable. I would think so but I don't know enough about databases.

So I am thinking about adding a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX teammgr_team_name ON teammgr_team (name);
```

Just having in mind it shouldn't be `UNIQUE` because the team name is not unique.

- Would adding this index help improve execution time?
- I've gone through the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) but is there any option that would be benefitial to my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query filters millions of rows to return a hand full of values. So, **yes**, adding this [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) will help massively:

```
CREATE INDEX teammgr_team_name_idx ON teammgr_team (name);
```

If your query always asks for `teammgr_team."real" = true` and that case is not the common case in the table, a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) would be even better:

```
CREATE INDEX teammgr_team_name_real_idx ON teammgr_team (name)
WHERE real;
```

Or maybe a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX teammgr_team_name_real_idx ON teammgr_team (name, real);
```

But adding a boolean column as index expression has typically limited benefit. It's typically more effective to have a partial index on the rare case.

That all depends on exact data distribution. And, possibly, on typical write patterns: highly volatile columns (updated a lot) are more expensive to index.

###### Aside 1

Simplify:

```
SELECT * FROM teammgr_team WHERE real AND name = 'abc';
```

`WHERE teammgr_team."real" = true` is just a noisy way of saying `WHERE real`.

###### Aside 2

Don't use basic type names like `real` as identifier. Leads to confusion. And "name" is not a good name, either.

Comment: When you say "If your query always asks for teammgr_team."real" = true and that case is not the common case, a partial index would be even better" don't you mean "that case IS the common case"? In fact, most of my team queries are against real teams, so it would be a good idea for the index to target only the subset of real teams.

Comment: @dabadaba: I clarified: "... and that case is not the common case *in the table*". If most of your rows have `real = true` anyway, a partial index isn't worth it. The *few* violating rows are filtered cheaply.